# Can Anyone Recommend Useful Oil droplets in Water Photos?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, effects, texture

I am trying to follow along this tutorial: http://www.computerarts.co.uk/tutorials/create-abstract-liquid-effect

But the oil droplets in water photo the artist provides as an example does not seem available for download anywhere.

Does anyone have any recommendations for a site that has similar "oil in water" effects?

Comment: I would just search stock sites or deviant art and try variants like "ink" in water or maybe "smoke"

Comment: Since this is not a direct question with a factual answer it may end up being too open ended. There is no true "correct answer". This does go against the questioning rules which can be reviewed in the FAQs. I tried answering the best I could, regardless. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

I think the artist never intended to give you the original oil drop image in the first place because he does say "now add a photograph" not "now add my photograph".

A few resources I know of include:

- Deviantart, do a search for any brush type + the word brush (i.e. oil brush) and you will get lots of free downloadable brush types. This also is a great resource for oil images as well to get you started.

[Oil Brush Search on Deviantart](http://browse.deviantart.com/?q=oil%20brushes&offset=0)

- Brusheezy has some free brushes and patterns you can try out such as this one:

[Brusheezy Oil Brush](http://www.brusheezy.com/brushes/31433-oil-spill)

- General list of brushes from a simple Google Search of Oil Brushes. Just use google image search to find a similar image for the oil drop.

[Google Search for Oil Brushes](http://www.youthedesigner.com/2010/07/08/31-sets-of-free-photoshop-paint-brushes/)
[Google Search for Oil Images](https://www.google.com/search?num=10&hl=en&site=imghp&tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=1686&bih=769&q=oil%20drop%20image&oq=oil%20drop%20image&gs_l=img.3..0.2164.4316.0.4409.18.11.2.5.5.0.140.820.9j2.11.0...0.0...1ac.1.3vcvoy3QA7g#hl=en&tbo=d&site=imghp&tbs=isz%3al&tbm=isch&sa=1&q=oil%20in%20water&oq=oil%20in%20water&gs_l=img.3..0l3j0i24l7.1380.10127.14.10265.14.12.0.2.2.0.97.756.12.12.0...0.0...1c.1.h_BC078x6T8&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.41524429,d.dmQ&fp=7e7fa5e03eb0822c&biw=1686&bih=769)

Finding exact images that you want will be tough since that's for you to decide. Please remember that all of this research can be done by yourself if you just search hard enough, these are simply suggestions for ways to start looking.

Comment: Thank you for the links. I did do several google searches, but wasn't getting the results I wanted. I thought someone may have had the photos in a cache, but I guess not. Thanks though!

Comment: A great idea would be to search smoke instead since the image used the tutorial looks more like a generic smoke image instead of a generic oil in water image. A search on google will give you all the images you need!

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try [CG Textures](http://cgtextures.com/). They have an 'ink' folder with quite some pictures like this.